# new FileInputStream() throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, linux, fileinputstream

I'm trying to open a file in my Android app as follows:

```
new FileInputStream("~/Meecha/meecha-8c85c-firebase-adminsdk-y2ze5-4324ffd28e.json");
```

I confirmed that the file exists in the given directory:

```
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/Meecha$ ls
app                local.properties
build.gradle       meecha-8c85c-firebase-adminsdk-y2ze5-4324ffd28e.json
gradlew.bat        settings.gradle
handshake_512.png
ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~/Meecha
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
~/Meecha/meecha-8c85c-firebase-adminsdk-y2ze5-4324ffd28e.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: That is no full psth. The file may be in the directory  but where is that directory?

Comment: @blackapps Actually, it is the full path to the directory that holds the file.

Comment: There is no full path on an Android device that starts with `~`. Full paths start with `/`.